# Include java project into android build

Tags: java, android, ant, jenkins

I've got such a problem

I have to include external java project into my android build.

The project structure is:

Alpha - project with shared classes and libs.

Beta - android project that uses files from alpha

Gamma - desktop java project that uses files from alpha.

Everything works fine on Eclipse, but I need it to work on Jenkins.
I'm using Google Android SDK (android update project command) to create a build.xml, and then I'm using google targets to do what I need (build, emma, clean and so on)

The problem is that this build.xml does not include files and libs from alpha project, so it basically failes at first line of beta build task.

My question is:
How to properly add alpha project as a dependency for a googles generated build.xml file?

Should I compress alpha to .jar and then add it somehow to beta (how?)
Should I just link it somehow?

Thanks for all help.

[I'm new to ant scripting so please write in plain engish:P]

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this sucks! When using Jenkins and sharing one lib-project on different projects, you'll have to compile your lib-project (alpha), as you already mentioned, copy the jar to the respective directory of both projects, and link them in the Build Path Settings.

This is quite a lot of ANT-Stuff, you'll have to look into, but don't get discouraged, it ain't rocket science :)

Basically you have to do this:

1. Create an Ant-script that compiles your shared project, and copies it to some lib-directory in both projects
2. Link the Jar in the Build Path of your desktop and android project
3. For Jenkins: Customize android's build.xml (e. g. add a new target), so that it executes the lib project's build.xml (compile the project and copy the jar).
4. Run it on Jenkins

If you don't want to compile the shared project (manually) each time before you run your android or desktop project in eclipse, you should add the shared lib's build.xml with the respective targets to the projects' builder settings (in Eclipse -> right click on Project -> Properties -> Builders -> add the new builder between the **Java** and the **Android package builder**).

Sorry dude, I don't know any other way. Maybe there is another solution out there, I haven't used Jenkins for a year.